# Suddenly no AC power to wall switch

Tags: switch, light, circuit

Got a led can light over shower that suddenly stopped working.

No AC to the feed wires of the can.

No AC to the wall switch that controls the light.
Both black wires connected to the switch are not powered.

No CB is tripped at the panel.

All other circuits in that bathroom and all surrounding rooms are working. Can't find a particular CB dedicated to that one light.

Wiring inside switch box:  Neutral wires connected by wire nut.  Load wires back stabbed into switch.  Neither Load wire shows AC power.

My thoughts are that it must be a disconnection between the switch and house power and that I will have to trace the wire feeding the switch back to a junction box or to the panel.

Edit:issue resolved.

For the life of me I could not trace the source of power to that light switch. I turned off the CBs and confirmed no power and I removed and checked all the wall switches and receptacles in the immediate vicinity to check for loose wires and to see if I could trace the wire from the switch back to power.
After having no luck I gave up and went to have dinner. I then put everything back in the boxes in the wall and restored power. Lo and behold the circuit was working again!
I ascribed it to my fiddling around with the connections to the various boxes and switches. Since there had been nothing obviously wrong at the various connections I was worried that there was something that would cause a short in the future that remained undiscovered.
Since I now had power on the circuit I could selectively turn off CBs to discover the circuit that the light was on.

I discovered that it was powered from the GFCI circuit from the guest bathroom, 20 feet away.
I remember testing and resetting that GFCI sometime in my trouble shooting but apparently I neglected to recheck power at the switch after doing that. Put that down to inexperience.

We had recent guests that used that bathroom and departed on the day before I discovered that the light did not work. He had an electric razor. I suspect that tripped the GFCI. I could have easily solved the problem if I had paid attention and could get my mind around the fact that an electrician would run a circuit from another bathroom. I understand why he would do that after thinking about it for awhile. There was only one receptacle down stream of the GFCI in the guest bath and adding the shower light in the other bath would divide the loads nicely and not overload the master bath GFCI circuit.

All's well that ends well. I learned something and nobody got hurt and nothing was damaged. That's a win.

Thank you to all that answered here to help me fix this.

Comment: Shower usually means bathroom, bathroom usually means GFCI protected power.  Check if any receptacles/outlets have buttons.  That might be the source of no power.  Lights in/near a shower usually are GFCI protected.

Comment: Back stabs are another known problem area. Screw use is usually recommended.  The switch might be powered from a receptacle, if back stabs are used there also, that is a chance to be the problem.

Comment: Lights generally don't require GFCI and generally you don't *want* them on GFCI. Exception: often gfci required for lights over tub or shower